# Dead visitors moving about, not being taken by a hearse

Tags: prison-architect

I had a riot and some people died including visitors.

The problem is that they are sent to hearse, but the dead people keep moving to south. The hearse goes away taking noone. This is an infinite loop occupying my guards.

What do I do?!

The following video shows the problem (start at 06:30):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=2487), visitor can't currently be taken by the hearse.

You could try going into the save file and manually deleting the visitor (make a backup before!). Otherwise, it will stay and haunt your prison... forever.

It [should be fixed](https://twitter.com/IVSoftware/status/410370410320912384) in the next version.

Comment: all right. I found this link explaining where to edit!
http://forums.introversion.co.uk/viewtopic.php?p=539844

thanks!